# jQuery JSON request

Tags: jquery, json, api

I am having difficulty getting the temperature object to read itself onto the page.
Here is the code for jQuery.

```
$(function () {
  var openWeather = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=area,us&appid=acddafd";
  $.getJSON(openWeather).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $(function (index, weather) {
      var p = $("<p>").html("The current weather in area: " + "<br/>" + "Temperature: " + index);
      p.appendTo("#openWeather");

    });

  })
});
```

If anyone can help get the object to load. That would be appreciated.

Comment: What **exactly** do you expect `$(function(index, weather) { ... })` to do? FYI, `$(Function)` assigns the function to the *DOMContentLoaded* event handler

Comment: it does the exact same thing that it does the first time you used it on line 1.

Comment: @KevinB I know that. I'm asking OP what they think it does and why they've chosen to use it there in the AJAX `done` callback

Comment: that wasn't @you. :)

Comment: @Mathew I think perhaps you want to use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), ie `$.each(data, function(index, weather) { ... })`. Voting to close as a typo